# How plot a discontinuous distribution function in R

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I hope i do all well, because I am new to this forum.

I try to plot a distribution function of discontinuous values like a cube

Can I do in r anything like the picture on this website?

http://www.dietrichgrude.de/stochastik/zufvar_vertfkt.gif

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `plot.stepfun` function. See examples of it with

```
example(plot.stepfun)
```

Comment: EDIT: Thanks a lot. Now I understand the command stepfun. With the parameter verticals=FALSE the plot looks really nice :)